# How to config ip address in embedded Linux?

Tags: c, linux, shell, embedded-linux

I'm working on an embedded device running Linux (with BusyBox). I need to provide a command line tool to config static ip address. There are some limitations.

1. Using `ifconfig` won't do the job because it will get lost when
   system rebooted.
2. With very limited resource, there's no GUI.
3. There is a `vi` text editor to modify Linux config file. But somehow that's not accepted either. Because the assumption is that the customers have no knowledge of how to use `vi` or deeper understanding to Linux. I need to provide a tool so that they can just press something like "ConfigMyIP 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0" and the job is done.

Any idea how this can be done? (Using `shell` or `C` or both)

Comment: It seems that you know which configuration file to modify, and what to modify in that file, and you're asking how to provide a GUI to achieve that modification. If so, there are probably as many answers as there are programmers. FWIW, I'd do it with a Tcl/Tk script; if that's not already on the box, I'd install it as, personally, scarcely an hour goes past when I don't want to write such a script.

Comment: @nurdglaw Not really. There's no GUI, just the shell, because of embedded device's limited resource. I'm not familiar with Tcl/Tk, but installing a new software is not an option either.

Comment: Are you running a webserver on the box? On what system are you expecting your customers to run the GUI? If that isn't the box, then how will that system communicate with the box? (Read "embedded device" for box :-) )

Comment: @nurdglaw Actually it's a very small device with very limited CPU speed, memory or disk space. So there's no way to install a GUI. Maybe  I didn't describe it well, I'll edit it.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with another solution myself. The general idea is to create a shell script that can config IP　address　in the system init directory. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio>
#define MAXBUF 100

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* f;
    char content[MAXBUF];
    f = fopen("/etc/init.d/configip", "w+");
    strcat("#!/bin/sh\n", content);
    strcat("ifconfig ", content);
    strcat(argv[1], content);
    strcat(" ", content);
    strcat(argv[2], content);
    strcat(" up", content);
    fwrite(content, 1, strlen(content) + 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

When this program was executed with arguments like "192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0", it will generate a shell script in `etc/init.d`:

```
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 up
```

The script will be loaded every time Linux boots up.

Comment: yeah, but you should validate the user input, otherwise the command can fail. As an example: incorrect netmask value o gateway outside lan.

Comment: @OttavioCampana Good point. I will add more validation. But for the purpose of simplicity, I won't update the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a program in the language of your choice that prompts the user to enter the required IP address? Then, copy the existing configuration file to a backup version and create a new configuration file by reading the backup version a line at a time.

If the line specifies the IP address, then discard it and write a new line the specifies the new IP address, otherwise just write the existing line.

If it's important that your customers enter the parameters from the command line, as shown in your question, then have a look at the documentation of the language of your choice to see haw to access command line arguments. If you're using C, then have look at the `argc` and `argv` arguments that are passed to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, the target runs `BusyBox`.

So why not add a [custom applet](http://www.busybox.net/FAQ.html#adding) to provide this "simple interface" allowing the user to modify permanently the corresponding configuration files?

I think this option could fit better than an *external* program with the very constrained environment you describe.